# XPiNC view icons

Tags: xpages

Is there a way I can load view icons (ex: vwicn001.gif) within XPages being rendered by XPiNC?  Most of what I've found only seems to work with web browsers.

My work around has been to use image resources, as that seems to work in both environments.

Comment: so using e.g. `<xp:image id="image1" url="/.ibmxspres/domino/icons/vwicn087.gif"></xp:image>` does not work in XPiNC?

Comment: Nope.  The XPages rendering engine prepends "/xsp/" to the beginning of the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a normal client installation (not Designer) - the icons are not there. You need to add them into resources