# xpages Column icon not shown in Notes Client

Tags: xpages, xpinc

There is an application which runs both on web and Notes Client.

I noticed that some icons are showed OK in my view panels when the app is running on browser, but there are 'invisible' ( not showing ) when the app is running inside the Notes Client.

My column icon code:

```
....

var iconNumber = parseInt(rowData.getColumnValue("$11")); // Programmatic name of the column
if ( formName == "fmTest1") {

"/.ibmxspres/domino/icons/vwicn" + (iconNumber > 99 ? "" : "0") + iconNumber + ".gif"} 


else if ( formName == "fmTest2" )

{  ""}}}]]></xp:this.iconSrc>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader3"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
```

Should I use other approach? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please try to check the source of page when opened in Notes client. I had a similar problem which I described in [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9363885/1047998). When viewed in XPiNC, XPages adds `/xsp/` in URL which may be the reason for icons not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Try using @ViewIconUrl(), which is a new SSJS @Function with Ext Lib and R9 http://www.intec.co.uk/new-notes-9-functions/.

However, from this question, the icons may not be available to XPiNC [XPiNC view icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890147/xpinc-view-icons). I don't have a Notes Client only install to check.

Comment: No, I finally used an imported .png image as icon.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is that add your own HTML `img` tag something like this:

```
<img url="/.ibmxspres/domino/icons/vwicn___.gif">
```

In your case you would have to render this code specifically using a computed text.

```
<xp:text escape="false" disableTheme="true">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:<YOUR CODE>}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

I described this technique on my [blog](http://naveegator.blogspot.in/2012/02/image-url-in-xpages-using-notes-client.html).